# Intellij Idea/Webstorm jsdoc analysis issue ,Unresolved variable

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm, jsdoc

I have a function where I declare the param asd

```
@param {HTMLElement} node
```

then later I use it like

```
node.parentElement
```

but it complains with Unresolved variable parentElement

I can't change the type to Node because I need it to be HTMLElement (I use .id later)

IS there a JSDoc change I can do to fix this or other solution (that si not ugly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Node.parentElement` property is not defined in Idea core javascript libraries ([WEB-21824](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21824)). You can add its definition as follows:

- Open plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\lib\JavaScriptLanguage.jar!\com\intellij\lang\javascript\index\predefined\DOMCore.js file in editor, copy its content to a new js file
- add `Node.prototype.parentElement = 0;` to it. See what other properties definitions look like to get an idea
- either add this file to your project, or set it up as a javascript library in `Settings (Preferences) | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries`  to get it used for completion, etc.

Note that this property doesn't seem to be standard (though it's supported by most browsers) - can't see it in https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-1950641247.

Comment: after I edit the copy of that file what is the next step ? should the original .jar be edited (would be replaced on updates)

Comment: you can replace files in original jar, of course.. but hacking them is not the thing I can recommend

Comment: can you edit the answer and add the last step, the one you recommend? what do I do with the new file ? (do I add it to the project?)

Comment: yes - it should be either placed in your project folder or configured as javascript library. I've updates the answer accordingly